Limit of value of 2 variable integral with finite limits and 4 integer parameters and obtain the form $\frac{0}{0}$ for numerator over denominator.
Assume  $j_1,k_1,j_2,k_2$ integers and $(j_1\ne k_1$ or $j_2\ne k_2)$ and denominator is product $(2k_2+k_1-2j_2-j_1)(k_2-k_1-j_2+j_1)(k_2+2k_1-j_2-2j_1)=0$
All first order derivatives of numerator wrt all integer param's are $0$ though 2nd order derivatives are not at the conditions stated. In the denominator all 4 first order derivatives wrt the 4 integer parameters are NOT $0$ because one and only one of the 3 factors in denominator are $0$ at the conditions given. The sum of the 4 derivatives of denominator wrt the integer parameters is $0$ but i still think that is irrelevant and the value of the integral, the form $\frac{0}{0}$, in these cases under the assumptions is still $0$ . Is that correct ?
Ok here i am posting from where i got this. Now do u really want to evaluate that integral yourself ? I already did that and is quite lengthy. The only thing u need to know is that the denominator is proportional to what i wrote above and in the numerator which is also zero at the conditions i gave is also zero and all it's first derivatives wrt the 4 integer parameters at the values of the conditions i gave above are zero. So what on earth else would u need. I can write out the numerator i got but i don't see whereas that is relevant unless u don't believe what i said. I don't care of the exact value of the integral if it turns out to be not zero but only that it is finite but i think the answer of the $0/0$ form is zero at the conditions values of the parameters i gave. OK so here below i paste the numerator which is of course $0$ at the parameters conditions i gave  and so are all of it's first derivatives wrt each the 4 integer parameters at the conditions i gave.It's second derivatives are not $0$ at those conditions. The numerator:

Numerator at the 4 integers parameters $j1,k1,j2,k2$ combinations as specified above is proportional to a linear sum with coefficients $\pm 1,\pm 2$ times one of the 3 cube roots of $1$,being $1,\exp{\frac{i2\pi }{3}},\exp({-i\frac{2\pi}{3}})$ ,raised to an integer power which can be a linear sum of the the 4 integer parameters at the condition(s) given above.


it would seem esp. irrelevant that the sum of derivatives wrt 4 param's is 0 because each derivative has to be multiplied by its associated particular dj.. or dk... which are independent.

This seems to me to be incomprehensible garbage. Numerator and denominator of what? Value of which integral?

i gave u the denominator. The numerator is rather lengthy so i did not write it. Why do u need anything other than numerator is 0 at all the param. values and all it's first derivatives are 0 wrt param's. if you really want i can write it out or post a copy of the book portion of 'Orthogonal polynomials of several variables' pages 50 and 51 to which this all pertains.

I think that the deal here is that you post enough for someone to understand the question. I don't think you have done so.

The answer is zero because the denominators come from
integrating the function as the last 3 part integral
from the reference Orthogonal polynomials in several variables book page 51 below proposition 2.9.1. I used t1 and t2 as the 2 independent variables and for the f(t) it is $\exp{((i2\pi((k2+2k1-2j1)t1+(2k2+k1-2j2-j1)t2))/3)}$
and after putting that into the 3 part integral above and transforming the part of the integral 2nd and 3rd parts that is integral over t3 terms, using t3=-t1-t2 and then putting all over a common denominator then i get after multiplying by $3/(i2\pi)$ the coefficient of t1 as the first term in the denominator and coefficient of t2 as the last and the center factor being the difference of these two. So now if one knew that the coefficient of any of these 3 variables were 0 then would not do it that way anyway. But for example for the integral over t1 if it's coefficient in the exponential were 0 then that part of the exponential would just be 1 so would just get integral of for example over t1 from 0 to 1 would just be 1 so would not get any coefficient of t1 in the denominator. I think u get the point. Anyway after doing this the whole integral as shown being the sum of 3 parts with product of 2 one dimension integrals in each of the 3 terms is still zero for j1 .ne. k1 or j2 .ne. k2. Its like doing an integral over some function of cosine(k1t1) and cosine(k2t2) assuming k1,k2 integers then one would often in general get some constant times k1 times k2 in the denominator after rationalizing but if one knew prior that k1 or k2 were 0 then the cosine of k1t1 or k2t2 would just be 1. And would use 1 in place of the cosine of either of those 1 or 2 zero terms so that k1 or k2 would not appear if it were 0.
